# Foreign key constraint with some where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have two tables, one with columns `accountid, category, code, name, desc` and the other with columns `id, accountid, code, reason, desc, active`.

Is there any way I can create a constraint such that `code` in the second table contains only values of `code` that are in first table with condition where category is `somevalue`?

Comment: depends on your database engine

Comment: What does that mean? (i am novice to sql server(ssms))

Comment: please tag the database you are using. ty

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar do you mean schema for tables

Comment: I mean for these tags on his inquiry sql foreign-keys constraints should include which database (oracle, sql-server, db2, etc)

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar it is sql-server

Comment: What FerdinandGaspar meant was for *you* to add the blue-boxed `sql-server` to the list of other blue-boxes at the bottom of your question. Like what I've just done for you ;)

Comment: I would use a trigger

Answer (score 1):

One method is a little trick.  First, create a unique index on `(category, code)` in the first table:

```
create unique index unq_table1_category_code on table1(category, code)
```

Then create a computed column in table2:

```
alter table table2 add category as ('somevalue') persisted;
```

Then create the foreign key relationship:

```
alter table table2 add constraint fk_somevalue_code
    foreign key (category, code) references table1(category, code);
```

Comment: I don't think it will work if the `category + code` isn't unique in the referenced table. Although, one can always throw the parent table' PK in, just to guarantee uniqueness (assuming it exists, of course).

Comment: @RogerWolf . . . If the values are not unique, then a foreign key could not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table2 WITH CHECK
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_table2category CHECK (category = 'somevalue'),
      CONSTRAINT FK_table2code FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES table1 (code);
```

Comment: This is not working,sql server throwing error near where clause

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StatusReason]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_StatusReason_ValueItem] CHECK([Category]='Status'),
CONSTRAINT [FK_StatusReason_ValueItem] FOREIGN KEY([StatusCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ValueItem] ([Code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StatusReason] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_StatusReason_ValueItem], [FK_StatusReason_ValueItem]

GO`